# Implement a generic trait that accesses bound structs common field

Tags: rust, design-patterns

I want to implement a "OOP" style constructor for several structs that share a common field.

```rs
trait Observer {
  fn update();
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct DisplayCurrent {
  station: &WeatherStation
}
impl Observer for DisplayCurrent {
  // ...
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct DisplayForecast {
  station: &WeatherStation
}
impl Observer for DisplayCurrent {
  // ...
}

trait SetStation {
  fn set_station(&self, );
}
impl <O: Observer + Default> SetStation for O {
  fn set_station(&self, station: &WeatherStation) {
    self.station = station;
  }
}
```

However, this will complain about `this.station` not existing (which is true, there's nothing ensuring it).

How can I tell the trait that the structs I'm about to apply it to they all have this `station` field?

Comment: You can't. Traits provide functionality in the form of functions, they do not specify how their implementors lay out their structs. I'm afraid this is an OOP pattern that simply doesn't apply to Rust. Don't forget, Rust is **not** an OOP language.

Comment: I feel your solution could require an architectural rethinking, which is sometimes hard for OOP programmers because OOP patterns come natural to them. It took me a while as well. But I can't really help you because I of course don't know your usecase. This might be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), meaning, you are asking for how to do it OOP style while the actual problem is that you are trying to solve your problem OOP style in the first place.

Comment: All I can tell you is that many times, after managing the rethinking-and-coming-up-with-an-alternative-architecture, the end result is kind of cleaner than it would have been OOP style.

Comment: The duplicate question answers the question. In case someone lands here -> Creating getters and setters in the trait would do the trick